# Hammer js rotation direction

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am new with Hammer.js and succesfully implements rotate recognizer:

```js
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var manager = new Hammer(image);
    manager.get('rotate').set({ enable: true, threshold:3 });
    manager.on("rotate", function (event) {
      console.log(event.type + " gesture detected.");
    });
```

This snippet writes to log 'rotate gesture detected'.

My question how I can detect direction of rotation(to left or right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `rotation` [in the event object](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#event-object) – it contains rotation angle in degrees (positive or negative based on the rotation direction). So something like this should work for you:

```
manager.on("rotate", function (event) {
  console.log(event.type + " gesture detected.");
  if(event.type === "rotate") {
      console.log("Rotation by " + event.rotation + " degrees.");
      if (event.rotation > 0) {
          console.log("Clockwise");
      } else {
          console.log("Counterclockwise");
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is that what i need) Will mark as answer! 
Thanks